# Vue: undoing removal of item from a v-for array if database write fails

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `v-for` loop of messages.  When the user clicks the delete button, I'd like to quickly remove it from the UI and delete the message from the database.  If for some reason the database write fails, how can I 'Undo' the deletion as if it never happened?  I was thinking of setting the `splice` to a variable but then how would I get back into that spot again?

```
<div v-for="(item,index) in items" :key="item.id">
   <button @click="deleteItem(item,index)">Delete Item</div>
</div>

  deleteItem(item,index) {
      this.items.splice(index, 1);

      axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/' + item._id)
      .then(resp => {
          if (resp.status != 200) {
              //UNDO splice of items
          }
      })
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get the element will be deleted, then insert it back in case the deleting in database failed

```
deleteItem(item,index) {
  let el = this.items.slice(index, index+1)[0];
  this.items.splice(index, 1);

  axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/api/posts/' + item._id)
  .then(resp => {
      if (resp.status != 200) {
          //UNDO splice of items
        this.items.splice(index, 0, el);
      }
  })
},
```

Comment: thanks Linh! I forgot splice can be used to insert as well.

Comment: yeahh, splice is for making changes to the array